# How to power an Arduino Nano without mini-B USB port?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano

I'm new to Arduino. I want to power my Arduino Nano with an external DC source, not with already attached mini USB port. I tried, but fail. Please help me to understand it. Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly did you try? What power source at what voltage did you connect at which pins?

Comment: I want to give 5V and I tried with pins 5v + GND and also with Vin + GND but no success

Comment: Should have worked if voltage, polarity and max current draw was correct. Read https://www.open-electronics.org/the-power-of-arduino-this-unknown/ Vin is the input to the 6-12V -> 5V voltage regulator. 5V is just the direct 5V net. Does the Arduino Nano still work when powered via USB or is it destroyed?

Comment: and I also tried with 12V on Vin + GND pins but no sign of power on nano

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Yes, Board is working with USB. LED is lighten up and I have uploaded code also in it

Comment: Do you have a multimeter to measure that a voltage is actually applied between the pins? Both methods for powering (Vin + 5V) should work (with the USB unplugged)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have multimeter :(

Comment: Just a thought in my mind, can it be damaged with static charge? I mean, some of the pins? : \

Comment: If it still works now when plugging it in via USB, it's still alive. If your USB port throws the device out, it's dead.

Comment: Duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60199/powering-arduino-nano-12volts

Comment: Thank you @MaximilianGerhardt and MatsK for being so sure and I figured out that it was my mistake to soldering wires loosly (Vin + GND) Sorry and thank you. :P